# General relativity from a mathematics point of view

Tags: mathematical-physics

Goodmorning,
I'm a university math student. I'm quiet familiar with differential geometry and I want to study the theory of general Relativity. I try to read some books, but all of these explain the subject from a physics point of view. Could someone give me the references of a book who explain the theory in a mathematics way? thank you so much

Comment: see this tread in physics.stackexchange, in particular Willie Wong's answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/mathematically-oriented-treatment-of-general-relativity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still like the classic "telephone book", namely the book *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler. It is a very good blend of both the physics point of view and the mathematics point of view.